# Android: вывод даты последнего изменения файла

Tags: android, java

Есть файл и нужно вывести дату последнего его изменения в человеческом виде.

Вот моя функция:

```
    private String dater(String DateFile) {
    File file = new File(DateFile);
    if(file.exists()){
        Long lastModified = file.lastModified();
        Date date = new Date(lastModified);
        return String.valueOf(date);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Она выводит дату изменения файла выводит примерно так:

**Thu Nov 14 17:33:47 Восточноевропейское время 2013**

А нужно всего навсего:

**14.11.2013 17:33**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

к выше сказанному остаются добавить только 
[android SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) и [про него же, но на русском](http://long-type.blogspot.com/2012/09/simpledateformat.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final String getFullTime(final long timeInMillis)
{
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    return format.format(c.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вам [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)