# Как форматировать дату с таймзоной в просто дату?

Tags: java, android

Как получить из этой строки `2018-07-11T09:54:40.660 +0000` обьект Date?

Comment: А чем это не время и дата? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: ну вот так отображать не корректно хотелось вот так  07-11-2018 09:54

Comment: А в вашем случае время это где? Лондон, как я понимаю. Вам точно лондонское время надо? Обычно парсят в `Date`, потом обратно в строку какую надо. И про часовой пояс не забываем!!!

Comment: вот вот я знаю как из датаформаттера  получать паттерн вренмени но как из этой строки получить просто обьект дате ?

Comment: Ну так бы и писали: _Как получить из этой строки объект `Date`?_

Comment: SimpleDateFormat: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271810/android-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/271814#271814

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен  SimpleDateFormat для конвертации строки в Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(StringPattern);
formatter.parse(your_date_string)
```

Что бы составить нужный вам паттерн, советую просмотреть [эту](http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/05/formatirovanie-daty-v-java.html) статью. В конце приведена таблица с паттернами.

Comment: а в стринг паттерн какой паттерн задать ?

Comment: тот который хочу получить или в котором находится это строка ?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Добавил статью, там все расписано.

Comment: @elik, когда парсите из строки - паттерн должен соответствовать входной строке, когда форматируете в строку - желаемому результату

Comment: @woesss благодарю вас

Comment: @Nuclominus благодарю очень познавательная статья